# Change case of first word of each line

Tags: string, bash, awk, uppercase

From command line, **how to change to uppercase each first word of a line in a text file?**

Example input:

```
hello   world  
tell    me who you are!
```

Example output:

```
HELLO   world  
TELL    me who you are!
```

There are no empty lines, it's ASCII, and each line starts with an alphabetic word followed by a **tab**.

Tools to use: anything that works on command line on **macOS** (bash 3.2, BSD sed, awk, tr, perl 5, python 2.7, swift 4, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `awk` one-liner:

```
awk -F$'\t' -v OFS=$'\t' '{ $1 = toupper($1) }1' file
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for words followed by a space. But actually, I figured out that my data has tabulations instead of spaces. Would you know how to avoid replacing the TAB by a SPACE?

Comment: Just updated the answer so that `awk` treats both space and tabs as delimiters.

Comment: OK, I finally came with a solution that fully works for me regarding TABs: `awk -F$'\t' '{ OFS = "\t" } {$1 = toupper($1)}1'`

Comment: You can achieve the same with `-v` option - updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can always just use bash case conversion and a while loop to accomplish what you intend, e.g.

```
$ while read -r a b; do echo "${a^^} $b"; done < file
HELLO world
HOW are you?
```

The *parameter expansion* `${var^^}` converts all chars in `var` to uppercase, `${var^}` converts the first letter.

**Bash 3.2 - 'tr'**

For earlier bash, you can use the same setup with `tr` with a *herestring* to handle the case conversion:

```
$ while read -r a b; do echo "$(tr [a-z] [A-Z] <<<"$a") $b"; done file
HELLO world
HOW are you?
```

**Preserving `\t` Characters**

To preserve the tab separated words, you have to prevent word-splitting during the read. Unfortunately, the `-d` option to `read` doesn't allow termination on a set of characters. A way around checking for both `spaces` or `tab` delimited words is the read the entire line disabling word-splitting with `IFS=` and then scanning forward through the line until the first literal `$' '` or `$'\t'` is found. (the literals are bash-only, not POSIX shell) A simple implementation would be:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do 
    word=
    ct=0 
    for ((i = 0; i < ${#line}; i++)); do 
        ct=$i
        ## check against literal 'space' or 'tab'
        [ "${line:$i:1}" = $' ' -o "${line:$i:1}" = $'\t' ] && break 
        word="${word}${line:$i:1}"
    done
    word="$(tr [a-z] [A-Z] <<<"$word")" 
    echo "${word}${line:$((ct))}"
done <file
```

**Output of `tab` Separated Words**

```
HELLO   world
HOW     are     you?
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes that is a bit early for the case conversion expansion `:)`

Comment: @Cœur if for any reason 3.2 doesn't have a *herestring*, you can do the same thing with `$(echo "$a" | tr [a-z] [A-Z])`, but better to avoid the pipe.

Comment: `sed` or `awk` will be quicker if you have to use `tr`. The *parameter expansion* is lightning fast, but if you are calling `tr` thousands of times, this is probably a job for the *stream editor* `sed`... `:)` Remember each *command substitution* (e.g. `$(....)`) and each call to `tr` will spawn separate subshells. (I would be curious about your `time sed...` and `time awk ...` comparisons...)

Comment: Your solution with `tr` is nice but it's replacing the tabs with spaces.

Comment: Yes, that is a limitation of *word splitting* that takes place with `read`. It can be controlled with `IFS` (the *Internal Field Separator*) or you can separate `tabs` and `spaces` by crawling down the string with *string indexes*. You can simply `read -r line` and then `for ((i = 0; i < ${#line}; i++)); do if [ "${line:$i;1}" = ' ' ] || [ "${line:$i:1}" = '\t' ]; then word="${line:0:$((i-1))}"; break; fi; done` and then simply check `"$word" != "$line"` and use `tr` on `$word`.  I'll update the answer in the morning -- it's way late `:)`

Comment: No worries, after going through the logic, it was worth adding just so there is a bash solution `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sed`:

```
sed 's/^\S*/\U&/g' file
```

where `\S` matches a non-whitespace character and `\U&` uppercases the matched pattern

**UPDATE**: in case of `BSD sed` since it does not support most of those special characters it is still doable but requires a much longer expression

```
sed -f script file
```

where the script contains

```
{
    h
    s/ .*//
    y/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/
    G
    s/\(.*\)\n[^ ]* \(.*\)/\1 \2/
}
```

Comment: I think that rounds out the ways to do it, `sed`, `awk`, `bash` -- covered.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice it should be on macOS. Added a general method for both `BSD sed` and `GNU sed`. I agree that the `awk` script would be much cleaner in the case when `GNU sed` is not available.